# setResult() not returning any result

Tags: android, startactivityforresult

I'm trying to get result back from an activity i'm starting. the problem is the setResult isn't working as it should :

```
    wortinfo_editsave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            if(extras !=null)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                boolean neu = extras.getBoolean("neu");
                if(neu)
                {
                    db.insert_word(wortinfo_wort.getText().toString(),wortinfo_bedeutung.getText().toString(),wortinfo_beispiel.getText().toString(),wortinfo_type.getSelectedItem().toString(),0);
                    intent.putExtra("res",0);
                    setResult(100, intent);
                    finish();
                }
                else
                {
                    db.update_word(edit_id,wortinfo_wort.getText().toString(),wortinfo_bedeutung.getText().toString(),wortinfo_beispiel.getText().toString(),wortinfo_type.getSelectedItem().toString(),0);
                    intent.putExtra("res",1);
                    setResult(100,intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

i've traced the program multiple times and all conditions are working correctly but only in one instance(first one, neu==true), setResult causes onActivityResult() to be called. i also have another block of code that tries to set the result and finish the activity but all it does is close the activity without returning any result. i've also tried changing 100 to RESULT_OK or other random numbers but it hasn't worked:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    switch(item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.edit_wort:
            ...
        case R.id.delete_wort:
            db.delete_wort(wortinfo_wort.getText().toString(), wortinfo_bedeutung.getText().toString());
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("res",2);
            setResult(100,intent);
            finish();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

i've read all the other questions about this but its a bit different since a part of the code isn't working while the if block above it works just fine.

Comment: Are you calling `startActivityForResult()` in the calling activity? If you just use `startActivity()`, you won't get a result. Also, it's typical to use the Activity constants `RESULT_OK` and `RESULT_CANCELLED` (not arbitrary values like `100`) when calling `setResult()`, and pass any information specific to your app in the `Intent` argument.

Comment: @Karakuri yes i was but the problem disappeared when i uninstalled the app, cleaned the project and built again... weird. thanks anyways